# How can I extract data from this site using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I've been following tutorials on how to scrape information using HTMLAgilityPack, here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace web_scraping_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Software&geo_location_terms=Sydney2C+ND");
            var names = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='business-name']").ToList();
            foreach (var item in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was easy to get the data because there's a common class name and it's simple to get to

I'm trying to use this to scrape information from this site, https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/354163#osu/780200

but I have no idea about the correct markup to get 'Stitches
Shawn Mendes' and the values given in this diagram:[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JOHt.png)

For the 'Shawn Mendes' the markup is `'<a class="beatmapset-header__details-text beatmapset-header__details-text--artist" href="https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets?q=Shawn%20Mendes">Shawn Mendes</a>'` 
but I'm not sure about how to implement this into the code. I've replaced the url and have changed the classname but the directory of this text seems a lot more complicated on this site. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

All of the details you're looking for appear to be in a JSON object in the markup. There is a script block with the ID "json-beatmapset", if you scrape the content of that, and parse the JSON it contains, it should be smooth sailing after that.

Comment: This really should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Although not an answer, it's a useful contribution, thank you baconbum - I'll be trying to scrape and parse this content